# Wrapping synchronous calls in an asynchronous version

Tags: java, design-patterns, user-interface

I have an application that I'm trying to restructure to use the MVC architecture. The GUI kicks off several long running function calls that would block the interface if I don't detach them from the GUI thread.

Now I was wondering whether wrapping the objects of the controller that have such long running functions into another version that just detaches the current call to a thread pool would be a good idea? Is there any pattern for this sort of problem?

**EDIT**
Maybe I should provide a sample. Currently my code is littered with the following:

```
env.getScheduledExecutor().execute(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    backend.someLongRunningMethod();
  }
});
```

Now I' wondering whether I should wrap the `Backend` into something like a `BackendFacade` class that will just wrap any function call into a runnable and schedule it to the executor.

It is worth noticing that most times the methods return `void` or I don't care anyway. In the rare cases that I need to get the value back I'll just use `Future`. It should not really be a huge change since I already decouple threads at some point but I'd like to consolidate how it is done across the whole project.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like some sort of asynchronous invokation. 
Usually different frameworks have different support for this

> @Async // Servlets/Springs does. GUI should have that also

If your framework does not allow this, then I can't see a problem in having a Thread Pool do do this.

Answer (score 0):

Going from synchronous to asynchronous is always a radical design change because instead of waiting for the result and in effect **pulling** it, now the background task needs to **push** the result into the appropriate place. In the end this looks much like any other Swing Listener. You can invent your own callback interface that you implement in an instance passed to the background task. The task will invoke the "result ready" method on that instance, which will invoke the result handling code.

There is also the `SwingWorker` class, but it doesn't implement a thread pool. Every instance will use a new thread.